# In Outlook for Mac, how to create a smart folder showing emails where I'm the only person in the "To" field?

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook

I want a Smart Folder in Outlook 2016 for Mac that shows all of the emails where I'm the **only** person in the To: field.

I've tried this, but it shows emails where I'm in the "To", but other people might be also:

```
(kMDItemRecipients = "Name, My")
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

When testing this, I can realize your requirement via following criterias:

[image]

Type your emails address in "To Recipient Is " option.
Please check if it works on your side.

Comment: It's close, but it also picks up emails where others are on the To: with me. It seems like the "Is" operator is working more like a "Contains".

Comment: Yes, I did further test. it will show all emails where my address is in the "To" field. If it is ok for you, we can also create a rule to move emails "Send To" "Only Me" to a specific folder.

Comment: I was trying to keep the emails in the inbox and have an alternate view with just the "Sent only to me" emails. Your suggestion let me to a decent path though. (1) Create a category called Only Me, (2) Create rule to apply the "Only Me" category to emails where "Sent to" is Only Me, then (3) create a smart folder for just that Only Me category. It has other side benefits also, but this is effectively the result I was wanting.

Comment: This is a great workaround!